# Install OCI8 with PHP-FPM on OpenSUSE

Tags: php, php-7, opensuse, oci8

I am trying to install OCI8 with PHP-FPM 7 on OpenSUSE 42.3, but the extension is not loading.

- I installed oracle-instantclient12.2-basic and
  oracle-instantclient12.2-devel with RPM.
- I installed oci8 php extension with pecl.
- I added extension to php.ini.
- I restarted the apache and php-fpm services.

In the log, there is the next error:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php7/extensions/oci8.so' - libmql1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Also, I tried different solutions, but nothing works:

Option 1: I added the next lines to the file /etc/sysconfic/apache2 and I restarted services:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib"
export ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64"
```

Option 2: I added the next lines to the file /etc/php7/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf and I restarted services:

```
env[LD_LIBRARY_PATH] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
env[ORACLE_HOME] = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
```

Option 3: I add the next line to the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf, I ran ldconfig and I restarted services:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks you!

Comment: What exactly did you do for those three 'Add' solutions you tried?  Details matter. (You did run ldconfig after your did the last one?)

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJones, I added more details in issue description. Thanks!

Comment: I would have gone with option 3 (and make sure to cleanly undo options 1 & 2 to avoid future confusion and conflicts).   Do you have libaio installed? (How did you install the RPMs?)  Don't forget that you shouldn't/needn't set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client.  Try running ldd on the libclntsh.so file and check all dependencies are met.

Comment: If I only do the third option, it works correctly.
Thanks @ChristopherJones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For install OCI8 with PHP-FPM 7 on OpenSUSE 42.3, we must do next steps:

- Install oracle-instantclient12.2-basic and oracle-instantclient12.2-devel with RPM.
- Install oci8 php extension with pecl.
- Add extension to php.ini.
- Add the next line to the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf and run ldconfig

  /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/
- Restart the apache and php-fpm services.